# Code runs fine on localhost but doesn't execute on gatorhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis

I wrote a small website in VWD. I am running it on my home machine using the localhost features of VWD. It runs flawlessly.

Now the backstory.  I had a linux server with gatorhost. I had them switch my domain and my server type to windows because i decided to learn asp.net(c#). I had a million problems with them hours on the phone. Issues with unable to connect when you search for my domain and my e-mail features and ftp features where all messed up took them hours to figure it out in multiple calls and tickets.

So now i think i got it all working i load my site through VWD onto my server (www.contentiousweb.com) All of my front end code works fine as far as form validation and links.

When i hit my submit buttons that would execute my c# code nothing happens at all. not a thing. When the forms are filled out wrong the validation works.  I got no errors or anything. i like dont know where to start.  Is it my code there server how much can i rely on VWD in being right because i cannot rely on my self lol.

Webconfig file.  (i swapped out my pw and e-mail)

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Ralph &lt;********@hotmail.com&gt;">
<network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.live.com" userName="*************@hotmail.com" password="***********" port="587" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Bellow is the button.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (Page.IsValid)
{
string fileName = Server.MapPath("_TextFiles/ContactForm.txt");
string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", nameBox.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", emailBox.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Subject##", subBox.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Message##", MsgField.Text);

MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
myMessage.Subject = "Response from  Contact Page";
myMessage.Body = mailBody;

myMessage.From = new MailAddress("******", "Contact");
myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("******", " Server"));

SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);

Message.Visible = true;
ContactTable.Visible = false;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

}
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appresciated.  i am new and learning but with my experince and problems with hostgator i think that it is something on there end because everything else has been.  i am clueless.

Please let me know if there is anymore information i can provide.  Thank you for any help

In my own troubleshooting i found this error just now using mozila dev tools.

```
[18:03:28.399] Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 @ http://contentiousweb.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=EJBSV2JIVC3wCtbtVqDWEZfeOsqUeA-l1kZnjjZKvx15e0cjnzPdj4H78hvszmtfrIhAM96VdUstdDjn1xGAbsydMzIjEQeNWDOz2tihnjEjxDW5esVemHLoHR01oIyUBoZTNPd7atx4-EPBnuVlWYbQIeLdoH_eBXy1j9kav6ac2ptv4Cl8sraaDBGXntVH0&t=ffffffff940d030f:1507
```

Thanks for any help i am still looking for answers my self.

Comment: Any errors logged in browser or server?

Comment: `[18:41:42.938] Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 @ http://contentiousweb.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=EJBSV2JIVC3wCtbtVqDWEZfeOsqUeA-l1kZnjjZKvx15e0cjnzPdj4H78hvszmtfrIhAM96VdUstdDjn1xGAbsydMzIjEQeNWDOz2tihnjEjxDW5esVemHLoHR01oIyUBoZTNPd7atx4-EPBnuVlWYbQIeLdoH_eBXy1j9kav6ac2ptv4Cl8sraaDBGXntVH0&t=ffffffff940d030f:1507`

Comment: right, so the server is unhappy; I can't read the server's mind... you are going to need to do some error logging on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it going. After talking with gatorhost on the phone for four hours we determined that the smtp information they had provided me would not work. They had me change my host to

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
<network  host="localhost" userName="*************@hotmail.com" password="***********" port="25" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And now it all works no errors.  Thank you everyone who helped with ideas.

Comment: Thanks for getting me out of a jam and saving me likely additional hours on the phone with HostGator support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code assigning the port number or credentials?

This code should work

```
// SMTP options
string Host = "smtp.mail.emea.microsoftonline.com";
Int16 Port = 587;
bool SSL = true;
string Username = "myname@mydomain.com";
string Password = "mypassword";

// Mail options
string To = "reciever@recieverdomain.com";
string From = "myname@mydomain.com";
string Subject = "This is a test";
string Body = "It works!";

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(From, To, Subject, Body);
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
sc.EnableSsl = SSL;
sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
sc.Credentials = netCred;

try
{
   Console.WriteLine("Sending e-mail message...");
  sc.Send(mm);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I got the same exact error message with this code. I call on the port and the credentials in my webconfig file. I tested it and runs great on a localhost. this is what i dont understand how different is a local host.  Thank you so much for the response though.

Comment: Can it be something host side? i have had so many issues that turned out to be host side before this that it is leaving me skeptical.

Comment: Try a different port. https://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/technical/commonly-used-port-numbers

Comment: So far i been trying and the issue i am now faced with is that only smtp.live.com is working as a smtp server. (only other smtp server i have is one the gatorhost gave me but i haven't been even able to get it to work locally or web.) If smtp.live.com on port 587 works locally shouldnt i be able to use it from my web server? gatorhost has it as a alternative port the only thing that i could see maybe giving me a problem is that it isnt a SSL port which i am trying to use SSL.